# Select rows with same values and time interval MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a big table in a DB in MySQL. This is only a limit 15 extract.

```
| name                 | etiqueta10      | msgtimestamp            | unixtime   |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+------------+
| SERTAN BOUEE         | 8a184cc44697fff | 2019-12-11 10:59:32.214 | 1576058372 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a47fff | 2019-12-11 02:29:54.387 | 1576027794 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f6641a08ffff | 2019-12-11 10:34:38.622 | 1576056878 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6b07fff | 2019-12-11 03:26:43.41  | 1576031203 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f0c17fff | 2019-12-11 01:42:49.941 | 1576024969 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a77fff | 2019-12-11 02:35:26.123 | 1576028126 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6b0ffff | 2019-12-11 03:10:00.187 | 1576030200 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 05:50:06.411 | 1576039806 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 04:18:54.378 | 1576027134 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 06:22:39.546 | 1576041759 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f44a7fff | 2019-12-11 04:13:01.891 | 1576033981 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f6641a08ffff | 2019-12-11 10:20:59.305 | 1576056059 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a27fff | 2019-12-11 03:05:14.675 | 1576029914 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f0daffff | 2019-12-11 01:54:01.929 | 1576025641 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f4c9ffff | 2019-12-11 05:14:46.724 | 1576037686 |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

What I want is to select the rows where etiqueta10 have the same value and also the diffence between their unixtime values is lower than 7200. Unixtime is the conversion of the timestamp values.

I dont know if there is some mysql query to do that. I am very new working with DB systems.
I have also thought doing some C code to do that.

Like in this extract I have three rows with same etiqueta10 value and with a difference lower than two hours of time.
The result should be:

```
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 05:50:06.411 | 1576039806 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 04:18:54.378 | 1576027134 |
| LONGLINE BUOY 06 89% | 8a3f664f6a5ffff | 2019-12-11 06:22:39.546 | 1576041759 |
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, MySQL can do this sort of thing. Please [edit] your question to add some sample output and more explanation of what you need.

Comment: I have added the result of the example of rows. These lines have the same value on etiqueta10 field and also the time difference is lower than two hours, it has to be both thing at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

you can self join the table on etiqueta10 with the condition of unix time stamp difference < 7200

```
select * from <table_name> where etiqueta10 in (    
select a.etiqueta10 
from <table_name> a inner join <table_name> b
on a.etiqueta10=b.etiqueta10
where abs(a.unixtime-b.unixtime) between 0 and 7200);
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me back repeated rows that have obviously the same 'etiqueta10' values. I mean the output is the same row again and again. I only want rows that repeat that field and between time interval, but differente rows. Thank you.

Comment: edited the answer to get all rows instead of repeating the same rows